# Using byte array to read in file, then display on ImageView (Android)

Tags: android, arrays

I was trying to display a picture file using ImageView,
although I knew that I could decode the file to bitmap directly,
but I have to do some other thing to it, so I could only choose byte[].

The code looks like this:

```
File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(Uri.parse(ImgUri)));
byte[] beforeData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int detectEnd = 0;
    while (detectEnd != -1){detectEnd = fis.read(beforeData, 0, 1024);}
    Bitmap b_t = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(beforeData, 0, beforeData.length);
    editImgView.setImageBitmap(b_t);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I tried to test out if I read in the picture correctly,
so I decode in to Bitmap then try to display it,
but it does not display any picture at all.

Is there anything that I misunderstood with FileInputStream?
PS. I use log.i to check and found that beforeData's length is normal,
but the data inside only get:
        [B@40c4b110   ,
which is not like a picture's data.

Thanks in Advance,
Desolve.

Oops, thanks you siliconeagle,
I forgot to consider that part...(At the very beginning I did)
However, it seems like it's not where the main problem is...
Now the loop looks like:

```
    while (pos < beforeData.length){
            read = fis.read(beforeData, pos, 1);
            pos += read;
        }
```

It's stupid and dummy I know,
but the code in this block should work properly, right?
However, I still couldn't see any picture in my ImageView.

Another PS:
The file's path is at /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1310368442822.jpg,
size 1485847 bytes,
would size cause any trouble?

Answer (score 1):

you are only reading data into the first 1024 bytes of the array each loop.

```
fis.read(beforeData, 0, 1024);
```

you would have to maintain a position counter (int pos) and use another variable (int read) to detect -1

```
int read=0;
int pos=0;
while (read!=-1) {
    read= fis.read(beforeData, pos, 1024);
    pos+=read;
}
```

make sure you close your files (fis.close()) as well...

The best way is :

```
File tmpImgFile = new File("/path");
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpImgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's still problem.